How to cover large patch of damp?
In this bedroom there is a chimney breast. There is always a large patch of damp when on the bottom left. It can be seen in front of the chimney breast and also the side. In the winter this patch expands to cover almost all of the bottom of the chimney breast. In the summer it contracts to what we see here.
We had the top of the chimney sealed so no rain and fall in. We also use hot air heater to make it go away but it stays.
I want to know if there someway to cover this part of the wall such that the patch is pushed behind and some waterproof substance is in front. Then we can just paint over the damp patch for good and live happily ever after.

I have tried a few things but for 3 years (since moving to this house), this patch has not gone away, it changed in size but does not go away. I am just fed up now. I want to contact the damp specialist but don't want to get ripped off.
EDIT:
This is a ground floor bedroom in a circa 1900 house. The other side of the wall is the outside of the house. There is no damp on the 1st floor room that contains the upper part of the chimney breast.

You will not get "happily ever after" with damp inside your wall.

I just want that it be hidden and I paint over it. I am fed up of this mess.

Even though the top of your chimney is closed off, then brickwork can still absorb water from the rain, and this will end up travelling down through the structure. It may help to apply a masonry sealer product to the part of the chimney which pokes up through the roof.

If you have a basement or crawlspace in that area and the floor we're looking at in this pic is not a concrete slab, then it's also likely that the moisture from the chimney has rotted the subfloor around it. I'd strongly recommend that you get underneath and take a look at the condition of the subfloor - poke a screwdriver at it and check if it's still solid.

I understand being fed up with this but if you cover it up and ignore it, you’re likely to cost yourself orders of magnitude more down the road in money and possible health impacts if you end up with mold on your hands.

So there's a drainage problem that has not been fixed. This is likely to be lead flashing that isn't doing its job properly, allowing water to drain from the roof down the chimney. Alternatively you may have a blocked roof gutter/drain, or perhaps fittings on the exterior wall (for a flue, for instance) that direct rainfaill against the wall rather than away from it.

This house is from 1900. I moved here 3 years ago. I am going to see what damp specialists are available. The one I could get in contact with said that it looks like rising damp. This is because these old houses have no damp proofing installed before all the bricks of walls are laid. He claims he has a solution that he can inject into the wall. Lets see who else I am able to find now that can give another informed opinion. Don't want to get ripped off.

@gyuunyuu " He claims he has a solution that he can inject into the wall." Sounds like a scam to me. Water will tend to appear at the bottom of walls even when it comes from above (which it almost always does.) Basically, the water moves down until it hits a barrier like a sill plate. It accumulates there and then starts to be absorbed by the wall materials. That wall is already pretty screwed up, you might as well open things up and see what's happening.

Not too long ago, I found a wall like this in a closet in my house.  It turned out that the water was coming from a pinhole leak in a cold-water pipe running above the front of the closet. There was no way to find it without opening the wall up.  After I stopped it and dried out the closet, a mushroom sprouted from a hole in the wall. Don't wait and don't guess about the problem

@JimmyJames rising damp is a real problem in older homes in the UK. At the age of house OP is talking about  a damp proof course was by no means standard, or may have failed over time. The remedy is to inject a mortar course with a damp proofing chemical to stop damp rising up the walls,which is what is sounds like has been suggested.

@ThaRobster I live in one wettest regions in the US and I have lots of moisture issues due to heavy clay soil. Maybe the building materials in those homes are like some sort of German shammy cloth, but it's hard to for me believe they would be able to lift water that high.  I've never seen anything like that with my plasterboard walls.

@ThaRobster In any event, that wall is done. Even if that's the issue, it should be replaced.  When I first bought a home, I had a window replaced and the contractor pointed out some rot. I made my life a lot harder than necessary trying to address it without opening up the wall. Years later, I have learned it's easier and faster to open things up and get it right. I get that it's scary but only until you've done it once or twice.

The other thing I notice when looking closely at that picture is that there's pretty rough gap between the wall and what appears to be some sort of MDF cabinetry. It doesn't look like something that has been there, untouched, for over 100 years.

The "cabinet" is basically a 3 door wardrobe was put there last year. Before that there was a built in cabinet which looked very old but I am not sure how old it was. It looked ugly and did not have the correct design so was removed completely.

@JimmyJames Google image search "rising damp UK" and you'll see much worse examples than OP has posted. Brick and mortar walls without proper (or damaged) damp proofing can lift moisture a very long way. And if you image search for "rising damp injection proofing uk" you'll see the fix which is widely used and has been suggested to OP which you write off as a scam. The difference is these are not plasterboard walls, they are either solid brick and mortar or brick and mortar with an air gap. No timber framing.

I got a quote from one guy, based on picture and description he said this is rising damp and it will cost 900£ to treat it.

@ThaRobster I didn't say it is a scam, it just sounds like one to me.  Where I live, 'basement waterproofing' is the thing. People will try to coat the inside of the foundation to seal out the water but it doesn't resolve much, improved drainage is generally the real solution. I'm just dubious of anything where someone claims they can inject something to the wall and fix a water issue. But maybe it works for this. Sealing it won't resolve anything if it's coming from above, though.

@gyuunyuu £900 doesn't sound crazy for this, but don't let someone go from a picture. Get a few people in (at least 3 to prevent over inflated quotes) to look at it properly and quote on that. From a picture it's difficult to say if it has spread further than that wall but they should examine it properly and advise accordingly.

You MUST open the wall and find where the moisture is coming from and correct that.  There may be insulation in the wall that is holding moisture. Open the wall and take a look.
Doing anything to just cover or "band aid" the problem will create larger issues.

This problem only happens on this chimney stack. Others have also said that merely covering it will create larger issues later. Why?

@gyuunyuu, Because you are not correcting the problem. You would only be covering the problem. Covering a damp area will lead to rot and mold that can grow into a much bigger issue and possibly compromise the structure of the home.

I live in the UK where houses are not fully made of wood. Also, this disgusting patch only occurs in this in one chimney in one room of the house and not rest of the room.

@gyuunyuu not being made of wood doesn't matter, bricks, mortar and plaster rot as well. If the patch has not gone away, it is not fixed. Best case scenario is that you paint over it and it soaks through the paint meaning you wasted your time. However this can lead to mould and rot which left unchecked will cause health issues, particularly respiratory. Plus when you sell, any decent surveyor would find this and it will really hit your resell price. But long term it will rot the fabric of the house and damage the chimney

I checked if the chimney could be removed in this circa 1900 UK house. The roof and first floor are held by Chimney support so it will cost more than 10,000£ to remove 1 chimney carefully. The chimney can't be removed but I could do anti damp paint on the patch. Then it should not cause mould.

@gyuunyuu you may be able to seal this spot and move the mould elsewhere. Imagine you could completely seal where the water is visible, but did nothing about how it's getting into the wall.  the saturated area will grow until you find a problem somewhere else.  It will happen. At some point the plaster will start falling off the walls as well

@gyuunyuu Mold will still form, even if under any covering you put on it. It will then smell, spread spores and generally be unpleasant. And Chris is right, eventually plaster will fall of the wall. The floor joists which are supported in that area will rot and fail as well. Painting any kind of product over this (even if is says Anti-Damp or Damp-B-Gone on it) will do nothing for actually getting rid of it. I get criticised a lot on here for recommending this , but if the best you can do is to paint it, you NEED to consult a (or even another) professional

@ThaRobster worse then that, Black Mold could grow. Which is toxic to humans. I agree, if your solution to a damp spot is "Paint over it" then you need to hire a professional.

As an FYI I had a damp spot on a wall in my house... Opened up the wall and found a lot of water damage because someone put in a window badly. Insulation was ruined, and there was some damage to the subflooring as well. The wet spot wasn't visible until long after the damage had started. Don't ignore it, it costs a lot more to fix the damage then it does to prevent it.

You will notice there is a vent on that chimney breast, there should be a corresponding one at the top of the chimney stack. These are necessary to clear any naturally occurring moisture, you can test to see if it has a draw by holding a flame near it and seeing if it pulls towards the vent. A blocked vent however would not cause as much damp as you're seeing, but it would exacerbate it.
Considering that this is the base of a chimney breast I would suspect the brickwork has become impregnated with hygroscopic salts, which attract moisture and cause damp. I would in no way rule out moisture ingress, however. In any case, at a minimum you will need to remove the plaster and expose the brick, salts will appear on the surface over a period of months if they are the cause. If not and the wall remains damp you will need to investigate water ingress, likely starting at the chimney stack.
There are no quick fixes for damp and there is a lot of misinformation out there!

The chimney stack has been close at the top. No rain can come inside now. I also used hot air heater of 2000W to blow air on this path for many hours. It has not gone away.

When a chimney is capped, it should also be vented, not sealed completely. This is because moisture can make its way into the chimney through the brickwork, and needs to have a path to exit. Checking the draw on the vent (visible in the photo) with an open flame will confirm if the upper vent is present and working.

Two things: you said that the chimney breast is entirely covered during winter with moisture. What that means is somewhere along the way moisture is getting under your shingles on the roof and draining down to your chimney and getting under the chimney breast.
When shingles do not keep out moisture, the moisture can freeze in Winter time, and the expanding ice from moisture shingle will push it farther out from its original, tight position. And more moisture can get in. In warmer months, the moisture trickles down the Roof and comes to rest around your chimney. The same thing happens: whatever moisture can get under the fixtures there can expand those fixtures and push them out. More moisture comes in, it freezes and expands, and any fixtures are no longer tight and must be fixed and re-seated. Including shingles.
Two, you might need a vapor barrier behind the wall to further protect it.
As for a contractor, find one that will give you a free evaluation. Do this with at least three contractors. Agree on the price and get that in your contract. Make them give you a detailed estimate including labor and supplies and a total cost. Then also agree how payments work: half now, half at the end? Payments? What are you comfortable with?
Make sure all of that is in your contract
What is the time frame? The contractor might be free on certain days or mornings or evenings. What should be finished when? What would they do to protect your house during absences? If the house is damaged, say from a thunderstorm or hail, what will they do to fix the damage caused by the bad weather?
All this should be in the contract.
We had a new roof installed, and while the roofers were gone, a thunderstorm destroyed one of the walls beneath.
The contractor said he'd fix it, but they couldn't give us the same material we had. It was wall board, a material thin as cardboard. You could thumbtack posters on it, which we sometimes did. They gave us the closest material to match the room: drywall. It was a step up from the wall board my Grandpa put up after WWII.
Look around on the web to see articles about questions you should ask contractors and what should be in the contract.
Good hunting!

As others have said, you need to find the source of the damp and fix it. You've said this is a bedroom, so it's probably upstairs. You may be able to see what's happening it by making a hole in the corresponding ceiling downstairs or by removing the flooring in this bedroom. Both of those options might be easier than opening up the fireplace. For the ceiling, if you have downlights in the right place you can sometimes remove those to give you access to the ceiling void without making a new hole.
If this is an upstairs room (or downstairs room with a suspended floor) I would be concerned about the joists if they've been exposed to moisture for years so it might be an idea to investigate further from that point of view.
You've said that the chimney is capped but water can still get in if the lead flashing is in poor condition round the base of the chimney. Adding a photo of this might help us to see the general condition of the chimney.
Is this room next to a bathroom, kitchen or utility room? Could the water be coming from another source? Are there any pipes that run in this area? Water can travel surprising distances.
If it was my wall, I'd pull up the floor, remove downlights, or use a cheap USB boroscope and poke it though the air vent holes to see if I could see where the water was coming from.
Sometimes the air vent cover is removable which will give you more access for  additional lighting. There's likely to be a build up of soot and crud behind the wall. Clearing all of that out might help (it'll at least make it easier to see what's happening). Use a wet/dry shop vacuum, not your everyday one.
Good luck.

As you’ve mentioned it’s a ground floor room, it could be rising damp.
1900’s UK houses don’t always have a damp proof course (DPC), so it is not unusual to see. If you check on the outside of the brickwork, you may be able to see a DPC (if there is one), often about 2 or 3 courses of bricks above ground level. Older houses sometimes used layers of slate in a mortar joint, often making the DPC mortar joint thicker than the other joints. (Newer houses use bituminous and then plastic DPCs in the joint.)
If your wall does have a DPC, one thing to check is that it isn’t breached outside - eg something against the wall, allowing water to bridge the DPC… soil, moss, wood, etc. Or that you don’t have water running down the wall, eg from a leak, overflow, or gutter issue.
Assuming that there isn’t a DPC, all is not lost… a specialist contractor will be able to inject a chemical DPC into the wall. DPC treatment typically also requires the removal of the plaster on the wall (often up to about 1.2 metres high) and replacement with damp resistant plaster to avoid issues with residual salts in the wall.
DPC treatment is quite common, but it has had a reputation of some “cowboy” operators in the industry. Get several quotes for the work, maybe even 6. You might find that one is significantly cheaper than others (it might be best avoided…), one significantly more expensive (ditto…), and the others quite close together; these are probably the ones you want to take more seriously. Make sure that the contractor you select is prepared to offer you an insurance backed guarantee for the work.

Good point (+1), though localised to the chimney breast makes it less likely.  It would be worth removing the furniture in the alcove on the left of the photo to check that.

Don't do this, if you like your house
Little children often believe that what you can't see cannot hurt you... But as adults we learn that this isn't true.
So what does this water mean? the wall behind this is wet, that wetness will cause wood to rot (leading to your house collapsing), it can cause brick/cement to degrade. It could create an environment allowing black mold to grow. black mold is toxic to humans. Even if you cannot see it, it will negatively impact your health. Basically water inside of a wall will negatively impact your house and/or health.
No good things come from trying to hide a wet wall.
What you should do instead?
Hire someone to tear apart your wall and fix this problem. Your desired solution is to hide it and hope it goes away... this means you are not qualified to fix this problem. Hire someone who is. Yes it will be expensive (Not really in the grand scheme of things, but more expensive then a paint coat), but fixing this now is cheaper then fixing it later once it becomes a real problem.
Beyond that, cannot give advice. I don't know what is causing the damp spot, My guess is some bad flashing on your chimney. And I also bet that  this damp spot isn't the only one. Its just the only spot that is visible to you.

I don't undesrtand "It is all made of all wood" do you mean its made completely of wood? Or something else

Sorry, what I meant is that, this is a circa 1900 house. It is not made of all wood like American houses. So I am not sure how such damp patch can affect it overtime.

Not all wood != has no wood.
Your interior walls are most likely made out of wood. And your exterior walls are firred out with wood for plumbing, insulation, and wiring.

Are masonry walls i.e that look from outside like they are made of bricks, are made up of wood somewhere as well?

The masonry walls aren't... But It is difficult to run wiring/plumbing thru bricks. So most houses that have a brick/stone exterior walls will fir those out internally with non-structural wooden walls so that they can put insulation/run wires thru the house. Those wooden walls won't cause your house to collapse if they rot out... Except for your 2nd level floor which is probably wood because its cheaper Then building it out of bricks... Barrel vaults require a lot more skill to make then a wooden floor.

And I realize you might not know what "fir" out means... It means to to put a false wall off of another wall to increase the thickness of the first wall. Its often used when remodeling homes to increase a walls insulation. Or when dealing with concrete/masonary walls to allow the interor to have drywall, insulation, and electrical outlets.

@Questor that's not how it typically works in a UK house of that age, pre plasterboard/drywall.  Cabling is probably run through channels in a thick layer of plaster (actually multiple layers) over brick (true for both solid and cavity walls).  Pipes tend to be run under the floorboards, which are separate planks and not tongue&groove, so can be lifted individually.

...In much more recent construction (my 90s-built house, but not 30s- and 50s-built houses I lived in before)  you do have plasterboard and it's often on battens (up to about 1" thick attached to the inner masonry of a cavity wall) leaving room for cables and thin pipes.  Plasterboard can also be glued directly onto the inner wall, in which case channels are cut, but that inner masonry is normally soft, some form of aerated concretre

@ChrisH Regardless of whether there's wood in this construction, I think we can be sure it was not designed to be continually damp. I think the OP is desperately trying to rationalize covering this up which is a very bad idea.

@JimmyJames yes indeed, and it's not like damp plaster is that much better than damp wood really.  It's just that I don't want to OP to get confused between what's said here and what their builder says

It would be worth checking for any external access to the chimney stack.  Probably not a soot door but just a hole going up into it.  These are designed to keep water out but damage or (possibly external) blockage can allow water to get in.
